# Gurobi resume optimization after model modification

Tags: optimization, gurobi

As far as i know Gurobi resumes optimizing where it left after calling `Model.Terminate()` and then calling `Model.Optimize()` again. So I can terminate and get the best solution so far and then proceed.Now I want to do the same, but since I want to use parts of the suboptimal solution I need to set some variables to fixed values before I call `Model.Optimize()` again and optimize the rest of the model. How can i do this so that gurobi does not start all over again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, it sounds like you're describing a mixed-integer program (MIP); model modification is different for continuous optimization (linear programming, quadratic programming).

When you modify a MIP model, the tree information is no longer helpful.  Instead, you must resolve the continuous (LP) relaxation and create a new branch-and-cut tree.  However, the prior solution may still be used as a MIP start, which can reduce the solve time for the second model.

However, your method may be redundant with the [RINS algorithm](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10107-004-0518-7?no-access=true), which is an [automatic feature of Gurobi MIP](http://www.gurobi.com/documentation/current/refman/rins.html).  You can control the behavior of RINS via the parameters RINS, SubMIPNodes and Heuristics.

Comment: yes you are right, i am using MIP and ill have a closer look at RINS (im quite new to LP/IP/MIP) - thank you for your answer